# How to change scaffold colour randomly on clicking separate file's gesturdetector button

Tags: flutter, scaffold

I have made two files... one is main.dart and other is homescreen.dart. Homescreen is for scaffold body which is created separately. Now there is a button in home screen for changing colour of scaffold. How to do this?

The main purpose is to know access scaffold from other stateful widget class file...

main.dart

```
class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: SafeArea(child: Scaffold(body: HomeScreen(),)),
    );
  }
}
```

homescreen.dart

```
class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: (){
        //My query is to PLACE CODE HERE TO CHANGE SCAFFOLD COLOR ON CLICKING
      },
      child: Center(
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.red,
          height: 60,
          width: 200,

          child: Center(child: Text('Change Color',)),

        ),
      ),

    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You can create a list of colors globally, then add the colors you want to that list. Then get a Color variable like Color myColor = Colors.wihte. This can be your starting color. And in scaffold make your backorundColor: myColor. Under onTap, make a setState(){} and make myColor to a random color from your Color list. For picking random elements, you can look up to https://alvinalexander.com/flutter/dart-function-return-random-element-from-list/ . That was the first thing came to my mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

**main.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'home.dart';
import 'dart:math' as math;


void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  Color _color = Colors.white;

  void changeColor(){
    setState(() {
      _color = Color((math.Random().nextDouble() * 0xFFFFFF).toInt()).withOpacity(1.0);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: SafeArea(child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: _color,
        body: HomeScreen(changeColor: changeColor,),)),
    );
  }
}
```

**home.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  VoidCallback? changeColor;
  HomeScreen({Key? key, this.changeColor}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: changeColor,
      child: Center(
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.red,
          height: 60,
          width: 200,
          child: const Center(
            child: Text(
              'Change Color',
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: It is Done...But is it impossible if I only allow to add code inside gesturedetector only? all other code should be unchanged.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this :

/// EDIT :

I edit it to get the Color random

```
import 'dart:math' as math;

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  Color _newColor = Colors.white; // variable with the color you want to change

  final rnd = math.Random(); // random
  Color getRandomColor() =>
      Color(rnd.nextInt(0xffffffff)); // little function to get the color random

  void _changeNewColor() { // function that you are going to send to yout HomeScreen
    setState(() {
      _newColor = getRandomColor();
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: HomeScreen(change: _changeNewColor), // function
      backgroundColor: _newColor, // here the variable
    );
  }
}

class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomeScreen({
    Key? key,
    this.change,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final Function()? change; // instance and get the funct

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: change,
      child: Center(
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.red,
          height: 60,
          width: 200,
          child: const Center(
              child: Text(
            'Change Color',
          )),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: No...My query is to change colour from another created file.....where I have created gesturdetector

Comment: So in your HomeScreen with the GestureDetector, you want to pressed it and then change the Scaffold's color in the main ?

Comment: Yes that is the point of my query

Comment: scaffold should be in the main file

Comment: Okkk, i edit, check

Comment: It is Done...But is it impossible if I only allow to add code inside gesturedetector only? all other code should be unchanged...

Comment: So all the logic in the GestureDetector and in the main nothing ?

Comment: yes to edit only inside gesturedetector

Comment: I see it a bit complicated because if all the logic of setState, etc... is inside the HomeScreen, I don't see a way to make the Scaffold of the parent change, so I recommend you to check then a state handler, either Provider or Cubit, with them you can make the logic inside the GestureDetector and listen in the main the change.